# What is the proper way to type lodash functions?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, lodash, typescript-typings

I'm having a hard time writing the proper types for a React component connected to a redux store via a selector using a lodash method.

Following [this article's conventions](https://medium.com/knerd/typescript-tips-series-proper-typing-of-react-redux-connected-components-eda058b6727d), a simplified version of my component would look like this

**reducers/index.ts**

```ts
interface ApiState {
  api: {
    entities: {
      subscriptions: {
        [pk: number]: {
          imageUrl: string;
          pk: number;
          slug: string;
          title: string;
        };
      };
    };
    result: {
      subscriptions: never[];
    };
  };
  …
};

export type RootState =
  | (ApiState &
      FirebaseState & {
        router: Reducer<RouterState, LocationChangeAction>;
      })
  | {};
```

**src/components/MyComponent.tsx**

```tsx
import React, {PureComponent} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {RootState} from "~/reducers";

interface OwnProps {
  label: "host" | "experience";
  score: number;
  subscriptionPk: number;
}
interface StateProps {
  subscription?: {
    pk: number;
    title: string;
  };
}

const selectSubscriptions = state => state.api.entities.subscriptions;


const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState, ownProps: OwnProps): StateProps => ({
  subscription: _.find(selectSubscriptions(state), {
    pk: ownProps.subscriptionPk,
  }) as any,
});

type Props = StateProps & OwnProps;

export default connect<StateProps, {}, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps)(
  class extends PureComponent<Props> {
    render() {
      const {label, score, subscription} = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
          {label} {score} {subscription.title}
        </div>
      );
    }
  },
);
```

**src/typings.d.ts**

```
// lodash global typing - begin
declare namespace _ {} // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
// lodash global typing - end
```

The code above works before the lodash find method is casted as any: `subscription: _.find() as any,` in mapStateToProp.

If I remove the `as any`, I get the following error:

```
$ tsc --project tsconfig.json
src/components/MyComponent.tsx:37:3 - error TS2322: Type '{ pk: { toString: ...; toFixed: ...; toExponential: ...; toPrecision: ...; valueOf: ...; toLocaleString: ...; [Symbol.iterator]: ...; }; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ pk: number; slug: string; title: string; } | undefined'.
  Type '{ pk: { toString: ...; toFixed: ...; toExponential: ...; toPrecision: ...; valueOf: ...; toLocaleString: ...; [Symbol.iterator]: ...; }; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ pk: number; slug: string; title: string; }': slug, title

37   subscription: _.find(selectSubscriptions(state), {
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/components/MyComponent.tsx:26:3
    26   subscription?: {
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'subscription' which is declared here on type 'StateProps'


Found 1 error.
```

**Why doesn't lodash figure out the types correctly ?** I would rather not have to cast all my lodash calls as any...

versions used:

- react 16.6.3
- redux 4.0.1
- react-redux 5.1.1
- lodash-webpack-plugin 0.11.5 (itself using lodash ^4.17.4)
- @types/lodash 4.14.119

Answer (score 1):

Just Dont Provide generic types to connect un nessesarly.

Here it is

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { PureComponent } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface IApiState {
  api: {
    entities: {
      subscriptions: {
        [pk: number]: {
          imageUrl: string;
          pk: number;
          slug: string;
          title: string;
        };
      };
    };
    result: {
      subscriptions: never[];
    };
  };
}

export type RootState = IApiState;

interface IOwnProps {
  label: "host" | "experience";
  score: number;
  subscriptionPk: number;
}
interface ISubscription {
  pk: number;
  title: string;
}
interface IStateProps {
  subscription?: ISubscription;
}

const selectSubscriptions = (state: RootState) =>
  state.api.entities.subscriptions;

const mapStateToProps = (
  state: RootState,
  ownProps: IOwnProps,
) => ({
  subscription: _.find(selectSubscriptions(state), {
    pk: ownProps.subscriptionPk,
  }),
});

type Props = IStateProps & IOwnProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
  class extends PureComponent<Props> {
    public render() {
      const { label, score, subscription } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
          {label} {score} {subscription && subscription.title}
        </div>
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply !
I tried to change `_.find() as any` → `_.find()` and `connect<StateProps, {}, OwnProps>` → `connect`, but the error on the _find line persists. This doesn't seem to be the solution. Also, I found the connect generic type declaration rather useful in understanding what it's normally expecting.

Comment: Your example also prompts an unrelated question. To be honest, I'm not yet clear on the differences between types and interfaces, and it pretty much look the same thing to me with my current usage (interface being a bit more flexible). Therefore, I'm wondering why several people use this I prefix naming convention to differentiate interfaces from types. Just a question of preference/habit, or is there a more serious reason behind it ?

Comment: I tried this on one of my solutions, And I use a linter that requires I Before interface names, It is just a convention. But, like I said I tried it and it worked. So if it is possible can you create a git repo?